# jQuery error blocking another script from firing in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using fancybox script as a widget to show videos as modal for "Most Popular" Widget section of the website.

Script used for this widget is creating problems for another on almost all the page & block jquery plugin from shows multiple image as slider (http://showcase.awkwardgroup.com/).

LINK FOR WEBSITE PAGE with error : http://tinyurl.com/cd32cn

error message: `TypeError: $(...).awShowcase is not a function` using debugger.

I would appreciate  help to resolve this issue so that all the image will work as shown in this link http://showcase.awkwardgroup.com/

If i remove the user Control for `Most Popular` then page works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the code on your page and I have to suggest you that steps.

- Move the `aw-showcase.js` script before the call of the `$("#showcase").awShowcase(`
   where is the error. Move it on the top, right after the jQuery load.
- Remove duplicate script load of jQuery
- If still not work, make the call using the jQuery, as `jQuery("#showcase").awShowcase`

Comment: I was struggling with this issue, What i did to resolve this issue was to put the CDE.jQuery.version on each page rather than master page. Which seems to be working for now, Even though i don't like this approach to add jquery file on each page. To me it seems error is generated the way page is rendered in asp.net

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker Do you do that I type here ?